# show current datetime not previous times vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

Newbie here.

So let's say I have 4 dates

10/01/2016 17:00 - 18:00

15/01/2016 22:00 - 2300

15/01/2016 23:00 - 00:00

16/01/2016 08:00

I don't want to output dates/ times that are in the past, but only show the current and next date. So show only 2 date entries not all dates after the current one.

Sorry I should have been more specific, I have basically created a diary with diary entries with a start and end time. It should show the current diary entry it's on. Datetime now only shows the specific time, and I have also tried to do startdate  < enddate but it captures the past dates

Answer (score 0):

Compare the date to the current date and time. The current date and time is available from the [DateTime.Now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx) property

You could probably google this answer in about 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three ways to do it, put this in a console program to test it.  One uses a for each loop, one uses a for loop by index, one uses a linq query.  I created and array, put some dates in them and then compared those dates to DateTime.Now().

```
    Dim dateList As DateTime() = {"1/1/2016", "1/15/2016", "1/31/2016", "2/15/2016"}

    ' For each loop
    For Each d As DateTime In dateList
        If d > DateTime.Now Then
            Console.WriteLine(d.ToString())
        End If
    Next

    ' Loop by index
    For x As Integer = 0 To dateList.Count - 1
        If dateList(x) > DateTime.Now Then
            Console.WriteLine(dateList(x).ToString())
        End If
    Next

    ' Linq Query
    Dim results = From d In dateList Where d > DateTime.Now()

    For Each d As DateTime In results
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString())
    Next

    Console.ReadKey()
```